# ArangoDB AQL: LOWER not working for value of slice?

Tags: arangodb, aql

I try following :

```
FOR d IN cresume FILTER d.isActive==true AND d.isPublic==true AND 'javascript' IN  LOWER(d.resume.skills[*].name)  SORT d.activatedTS DESC LIMIT 200 RETURN d
```

idea is to check if (lowercase) javascript is in skills[*] name. This don't find Result. If I do:

```
FOR d IN cresume FILTER d.isActive==true AND d.isPublic==true AND 'JavaScript' IN  d.resume.skills[*].name  SORT d.activatedTS DESC LIMIT 200 RETURN d
```

I get the result

Question... Is LOWER not working on a value from an [*] Array/Slice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got info from Arango Support. As documented, LOWER works on strings. But instead of `LOWER(d.resume.skills[*].name)` you can use `d.resume.skills[* RETURN LOWER(CURRENT.name)]`